# Hash Sum mismatch for "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libwebp6 amd64 0.6.1-2"

Tags: apt, nginx

I am trying to install nginx on a brand new ubuntu installation from vagrant `ubuntu/bionic64` box.

I have tried the following commands (as sudo) in order:

`apt update` - [result](https://pastebin.com/raw/fm8jDwVH)

`apt -y install nginx` - [result](https://pastebin.com/raw/FViccHDV)

Then as suggested, I tried the `--fix-mission` option too:

`apt --fix-missing update` - [result](https://pastebin.com/raw/tEkPSuku)

`apt -y install nginx` - [result](https://pastebin.com/raw/AHmW42dm)

It is still failing with "Hash Sum mismatch" for "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libwebp6 amd64 0.6.1-2"

I have verified that the file "libwebp6_0.6.1-2_amd64.deb" exists in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libw/libwebp/ but I still get the error. What else can I try?